# Difference between two datetime in milliseconds (Informix)

Tags: sql, datetime, informix

I could find something like this to find difference in seconds. But I am not able to find how to find difference in milliseconds.

```
select (start_time - datetime(2013-08-12 19:05:34.223) year to fraction(3))
    ::interval second(9) to second 
    from table1 where event_id = 1
```

Comment: I want to do this in java. So just in case if there is some java specific crude way to achieve this.

Comment: What do you exactly need to achieve? What have you tried to accomplish it?

Comment: the code you have posted is sql query ,there is nothing to do with java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First , if you really want the milliseconds detail from the database, you need to check if the USEOSTIME parameter is activated (by default isn't).
Informix only show the fractional/milliseconds when the database is configured to use the OS TIME (this means they use the OS gettime() function).
When this option is deactivated the fractional part always be zeros.

If it isn't activated , you or the DBA need to change this at the onconfig file and restart the engine.

**Just careful** , because this will affect all timestamps used at your datadabase.

```
select * from sysmaster:sysconfig where cf_name = 'USEOSTIME';
    cf_id         54
    cf_name       USEOSTIME
    cf_flags      0
    cf_original   1
    cf_effective  1
    cf_default    0
    1 row(s) retrieved.

drop table if exists tp01;
    Table dropped.

create temp table tp01 ( dt datetime year to fraction );
    Temporary table created.
insert into tp01 values ( current);
    1 row(s) inserted.

select * from tp01;
    dt
    2013-10-18 08:29:36.864
    1 row(s) retrieved.
select dt, current, (current - dt)::interval second(9) to fraction from tp01;
    dt                      (expression)            (expression)
    2013-10-18 08:29:36.864 2013-10-18 08:29:36.864          0.000
    1 row(s) retrieved.
select dt, current, ((current - dt)::interval second(9) to fraction)*1000 from tp01;
    dt                      (expression)            (expression)
    2013-10-18 08:29:36.864 2013-10-18 08:29:36.865          1.000
    1 row(s) retrieved.
```

Here, after wait 8 seconds and I re-run the selects above...

```
dt                      (expression)            (expression)
2013-10-18 08:30:44.539 2013-10-18 08:30:53.058          8.519

dt                      (expression)            (expression)
2013-10-18 08:30:44.539 2013-10-18 08:30:53.058       8519.000
```

Comment: Great help !!!! And very informative ... Thanks Bud. Just one quick Q .. what does 9 stands for in "second(9)"

Comment: @Andy897 so your question was not targeted for Java after all =\

Comment: When use interval you need specify the "range" of the bigger value , for example you can have this value into interval datetype: `10432.455` what means 10,432 seconds. The (9) means you can use 9 digits ~= 999,999,999 seconds, if you limit to (3) then you can have values limited to 999 seconds....... plus: This can be easily converted to days using the cast `::interval day(3) to second`.

Comment: I forgot to say .... the USEOSTIME is useful only if you use the `current` statement, if your fractional values are input from your application don't worry with USEOSTIME , all calculations should be work without problem.

Answer (score -4):

Sorry for java specific code but below is the sql code that can be useful to u :

```
select (datediff(ss,StartDate,EndDate)*1000)
```

Comment: .... I'm not sure that Informix has a `datediff()` function.  Note that the DB2 version returns an estimate, which will often be worthless.

Comment: this function don't exists at informix (current version , 12.10)

Comment: datediff function is belongs to mssql